Why is my GCC version not the latest?
Does this make sense? The version is:
me@me-All-Series:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

me@me-All-Series:~$ sudo apt install gcc
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc is already the newest version (4:9.3.0-1ubuntu2).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 3 not to upgrade.

What version is that? GCC is supposedly up to version 14.

Yes it makes sense - see for example Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?

@steeldriver So what version is that I've got? 9.3.0 How old is that? Also what's the 4: mean ?

You're using the 2020-April (20.04) release of Ubuntu, your OS was built using packages that existed during the development cycle of your OS (late 2019 & early 2020); ie. you're using a release that has had 8 newer systems released since your system was produced.  If you want newer software, release-upgrade to a newer OS.

Yes you've got 9.3.0, which dates from 2020 (same as your OS release) - use apt changelog gcc-9 for details. The 4: is an epoch number - see Why do some packages have extra numbers before a colon on the front of their version string?

BTW, your default gcc version may be whatever, but apt-cache search gcc | grep "^gcc" should show that up to gcc-10 is available to install.

@mchid OK, I ended up installing gcc-13, and now I have gcc-13 in my user/bin, but there's g++, I thought that installing gcc also installs the c++ compiler. CMake can't find gcc because it must look for gcc, so I set the CMAKE_C_COMPILER to gcc-13, but yeah, there's c++ compiler.

Also, you're running the latest version of gcc-9 the same way someone would run the latest updated version of like Windows 10 instead of Windows 11. It's up to date for bugs and security patches, it's just not the newest gcc that has been released. Also, if you install gcc-10, you'd simply call it explicitly when using it instead of using the generic gcc command.

@mchid I don't get this, my version says it's 20.04.6. I look up Wikipedia and it says the latest version of Ubuntu is 20.04 released 25 days ago. Why are you saying that my version is from year 2000? And how can you tell?

Not sure how you installed gcc-13 on 20.04 as the default repositories only provide up to gcc-10 but if you installed a ppa, I'd have a look at apt-cache search g++ | grep "^g++-"

24.04 is from 25 days ago, April of 2024 (24.04). Version 20.04 was from April of 2020 which is also the same version I'm using.

@mchid Oh OK. I installed gcc-13, but I have no c++ compiler which is g++. I have to install that separately? In my usr/bin folder I have gcc-9 gcc-13 but not g++ anywhere.

Also, take a look at find /usr/bin/g+* to see if there are any other versions installed.

@mchid Nope, no such file, I guess I have to install that separately. But I thought installing gcc installed g++

Yeah, if it's specifically looking for a g++ something then it looks like that would need to be installed separately as apt-file search g++  only shows packages like g++ and g++-10 If apt-file isn't already set up, you'd need to install it: sudo apt install apt-file and then update sudo apt-file update and then search apt-file search /usr/bin/g++ to show what packages provide the files searched for.

@mchid This is very very complicated. Anyway, I made the switch to Linux Mint, so far I'm enjoying it a lot more. And thank you very much.
